# Correct way to claim ownership of existing raw pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, constants, unique-ptr

I have some code that claims ownership of a sequence of raw pointers, and am wondering if there is an acceptable way to do this? What I'm looking for is a way to enforce the ownership in code to a greater degree. Mainly, I've been wondering whether or not my constructor should be taking a vector of unique pointers directly.

As a sidenote, once ownership has been claimed, the data is supposed to be immutable.

The code follows roughly the pattern of `class X` below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; // For readability purposes only

class X {
public:
    const vector< unique_ptr<const int> > data; // In my case this is private

    // Constructor: X object will take ownership of the data 
    // destroying it when going out of scope
    X (vector<int*> rawData) 
        : data { make_move_iterator(rawData.begin()), make_move_iterator(rawData.end()) }
    { }
};


int main() {
    // Illustrating some issues with claiming ownership of existing pointers:
    vector<int*> rawData { new int(9) , new int(4) };
    int* rawPointer = rawData[0];
    { // New scope
        X x(rawData);
        cout << *(x.data[0]) << endl; // Unique pointer points to 9
        *rawPointer = 7;
        cout << *(x.data[0]) << endl; // Unique pointer points to 7
    }
    cout << *rawPointer << endl; // The pointer has been deleted, prints garbage
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A single owning raw pointer is bad enough. A vector of owning raw pointers? That's pretty hard to beat, as far as antipatterns go.

Comment: Use `unique_ptr`, please.

Comment: You don't need a move iterator here, since `int*` does not have a move constructor...

Comment: "I've been wondering whether or not my constructor should be taking a vector of unique pointers directly" — Yes, please.

Comment: If the construction of `rawData` throws in allocating its buffer, the news in the initializer list are leaked.  If the construction of `data` throws in allocating its buffer, all of `rawPointer` is leaked.  You've got to get those allocated pointers owned right away to achieve basic exception safety.

Comment: `move_iterator` does nothing when applied to a sequence of raw pointers.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Sorry about code quality, the raw pointers actually point to user defined objects in my code, and the move pattern was leftover from trying to take unique pointers in the constructor. Anyone want to post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You don't *claim ownership* of resources. Ownership is *given* by the previous owner. Then you don't have the possibility of multiple places thinking they each own the same resource, or nowhere thinking it owns a resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to post an answer without detailed knowledge of your situation.  But my recommendation is to attach your data to a `unique_ptr` as soon as it is known.  Then you can move that `unique_ptr` into and out of `vector`s at will.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; // For readability purposes only

class X {
public:
    const vector< unique_ptr<const int> > data; // In my case this is private

    // Constructor: X object will take ownership of the data 
    // destroying it when going out of scope
    X (vector<unique_ptr<const int>>&& v) 
        : data { std::move(v) }
    { }
};

vector<unique_ptr<const int>>
collectRawData()
{
    auto rawData = {9, 4};
    vector<unique_ptr<const int>> data;
    for (auto const& x : rawData)
        data.push_back(make_unique<int>(x));
    return data;
}

int main() {
    auto rawData = collectRawData();
    { // New scope
        X x(std::move(rawData));
        cout << *(x.data[0]) << endl; // Unique pointer points to 9
        cout << *(x.data[1]) << endl; // Unique pointer points to 4
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, this seems like the way to go, although moving and initializing unique pointers is a bit of a pain.

Comment: @Oystein write `std::unique_ptr<T> to_unique(T* t){return std::unique_ptr<T>(t);}`, as well as `make_unique<T>`, to make creating and/or stealing ownership less annoying.  (never, ever do a `to_unique( new T() )`, do a `make_unique<T>()`).  Moving them around is the entire point, recording where ownership lies in code is important if you want code that works more than just "by accident".

Answer (score 0):

You did several misstakes.

1. In case of `const vector< unique_ptr<const int> >` data; a move iterator does make not that much sense. The reason why is, `int*` doesn't have a move constructor.
2. If you call `X`'s constructor `X (vector<int*> rawData)` with `vector < int* >` so the copy constructor of `vector < int* >` gets called, but that's not what you want to.
   Btw. the reason why to use move is, to avoid big memory copies. For instance `std::vector < int* >`: The member attribute size and the pointer to the memory location where your `int*`s are stored of `std::vector<int*>` must be copied by a move too but not the `int*s` self. A conclusion is that move is there to claim ownership.
3. If you want shared pointers like that, use `std::shared_ptr`. It owns a counter, which counts the ptrs which pointing to itself.

´
My Example Code:

```
class X
{
public:
    const std::vector< std::shared_ptr< const int> > data; // In my case this is private

    // Constructor: X object will take ownership of the data 
    // destroying it when going out of scope
    X (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>& rawData) 
        //: data(rawData)
        : data(rawData.cbegin(), rawData.cend())
    { }
};


int main() {
    // Illustrating some issues with claiming ownership of existing pointers:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> rawData { std::make_shared<int>(9), std::make_shared<int>(4) };
    int* rawPointer = rawData[0].get();
    { // New scope
        X x(rawData);
        cout << *(x.data[0]) << endl; // Unique pointer points to 9
        *rawPointer = 7;
        cout << *(x.data[0]) << endl; // Unique pointer points to 7
    }
    cout << *rawPointer << endl; // The pointer has been deleted, prints not more garbage
    return 0;
}
```

If you dont want use `std::shared_ptr`, you will need an GC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not sure `shared_ptr` makes sense in this context, since there should be a transfer of ownership and there really only is one owner.

Comment: You want to transfair the ownership to int* rawPointer?

Comment: The idea is that the X object should claim ownership of the pointer upon construction